# checking existence of a ruby object and testing attributes of that object in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Kind of a newbie question here but I promise it is really hard to google for. What I want to do is test the attribute of an object and test the existence of that same object in one line. I could do this:

```
user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
if user
  if user.access_token == params[:access_token]
    puts "success"
  else
    puts "failure"
  end
else
  puts "failure"
end
```

I would like to seriously re-factor this and get rid of the nested if statements. Thing is, I can't do something like

```
if user && user.access_token
```

since in the case where user is actually nil, Ruby will throw an error when trying to evaluate nil.access_token. Anybody know the actual correct way to re-factor this into one line? Is it even possible, or are the nested if statements the only way?

Comment: if user is null or false and there is an && next to it, will it still evaluate? Doesnt ruby follow short circuit evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `user && user.access_token` is fine since Ruby will stop evaluating the expression once it encounters one `false` condition.

This is known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: I find `and` works better for cases like this because of the very loose binding on it, but it's mostly a matter of preference.